# (VC2010 express) 2D array misbehaving

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, grid

Im using VC2010 express and am encountering an result I can't quite grasp.
My code is as follows:

```
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int gridSize = 2;
    int grid[gridSize][gridSize];

    for(int x=1; x <= gridSize; x++){
        for(int y=1; y <= gridSize; y++){
            grid[x][y] = 0;
        }

    }
    for(int i=0; i <= gridSize; i++){
        grid[i][0] = 1; // set the horizontal line to 1's
        grid[0][i] = 1; // set the vertical line to 1's
    }

    int rows = 0;
    while(rows <= gridSize){
        for(int i=0; i<=gridSize; i++){
            cout << grid[i][rows] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        rows++;
    }

    clock_t wait;
    wait = clock();
    while (clock() <= (wait + 500000));  // Wait for 500 seconds and then continue
    wait=0;
}
```

I am expecting this code to result in:

- 1 1 1
- 1 0 0
- 1 0 0

Instead it results in:

- 1 1 1
- 1 0 0
- 1 1 0

I dont understand how its possible for this code to fill grid[1][2] with 1.
Any thoughts on that?

**EDIT:**
Can't answer my own question right now.. But I've solved the lattice paths problem! :)
Ended up with this code to calculate the amount of lattice paths in a grid:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int gridSize = 3;
    int grid[gridSize+1][gridSize+1];

    for(int i=0; i <= gridSize; i++){
        grid[i][0] = 1; // set the horizontal line to 1's
        grid[0][i] = 1; // set the vertical line to 1's
    }

    for(int x=1; x <= gridSize; x++){
        for(int y=1; y <= gridSize; y++){
            grid[x][y] = grid[x-1][y] + grid[x][y-1];
        }
    }

    cout << "Amount of lattice paths for a " << gridSize << "x" << gridSize << " grid: " << grid[gridSize][gridSize];

    clock_t wait;
    wait = clock();
    while (clock() <= (wait + 500000));  // Wait for 500 seconds and then continue
    wait=0;
}
```

Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: `i<=gridSize` in the for loop - instant UB! You don't even have to pay for it!

Comment: Just start your day with a debugger :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you array index is out of bound, for example:

```
for(int x=1; x <= gridSize; x++){
```

should be:

```
for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
                 ^ removed =
```

you should run your loop for index value `[0 to gridSize)`, and yes this misbehave is called [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C standard.

Comment: Right you are, I was actually intending the for loops to be <=, merely forgot to declare the array on gridSize + 1. I was trying to solve the project euler 15th problem.

Comment: @Pwnball Good luck Pwnball!

Comment: @Pwnball Not only that you also need to keep in mind that array indexing starts from `0`

Comment: @PHIfounder, I am indeed aware! But nontheless thanks for pointing it out ;-)